# Variable parameters for input table and field name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, parameters

I searched for others who've asked this question but I couldn't quite find one that matched what I'm trying to do.

I want to make a model that aggregates three address point feature classes and merges them into a single address point feature class with a single field containing the address. Assume all three source feature classes already have some field that contains the address attribute, but each uses a different field name for it.

- The source data might be saved in different places each time the tool is run, so I want the user to  navigate to the input feature classes (x3, once for each of the inputs).
- Once each input feature class is chosen, I would like a drop-down of the field names in that input table, so that the user can indicate which field contains the address information (i.e., which one to 'keep' in the field mapping of the merge). This is x3 as well, once for each input.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. It seems like it should be simple, but I'm afraid I'm going to end up having to bash the whole thing out into a python script (which I'm clumsy at).

Am I missing something that's already built-in and available in ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

I think the tool you are looking for is [Get Field Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm). This link is for ArcGIS 10.x but there is an similar tool for ArcGIS Pro [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/get-field-value.htm).  In your model, right click a white area, choose Model Only Tools, select Get Field Value.